# Netstandard1.x Nuget packages cannot be installed for netstandard1.x projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-core, .net-standard

After doing a fresh Windows 10 installation along with latest Visual Studio 2015, netcore, and nuget tooling - I can no longer install Nuget packages to any .netstandard projects. Here's some example output:

```
Restoring packages for 'ClassLibrary1'.
Restoring packages for c:\users\zone1\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\project.json...
Package System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync 4.0.11 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync 4.0.11 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
Package restore failed for 'ClassLibrary1'.
```

I created the project ClassLibrary1 as a portable class library, change the target to netstandard1.3, and cannot install any Nuget packages that show support for netstandard1.3. Same goes for netstandard1.5 and the other versions.

I just trying pulling and building the source for [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (a project that supports .netstandard) to verify I wasn't setting up my project wrong and am getting the same problem:

```
Errors in C:\Users\zone1\Repos\MailKit\MailKit\MailKit.CoreFX.xproj
    Package System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.1.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package System.Net.NetworkInformation 4.1.0 supports:
      - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
      - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
      - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
      - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
      - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
      - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
      - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
      - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
      - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
      - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
      - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
      - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
```

I've posted some more details here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3433

This all worked before I reformatted with a fresh Windows installation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try running "nuget.exe locals -clear all" command?

Comment: This seems to fix the problem. Thanks! I'm going to give a more detailed answer to the question since it looks like a common problem for people.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got a working solution thanks to a tip from [@eddie-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5475003/eddie-msft).

Download the latest nuget commandline util from here https://dist.nuget.org/index.html ([v3.5.0-rc1](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v3.5.0-rc1/NuGet.exe) at the time of posting)

Then run:

`nuget.exe locals -clear all`

I made sure to have VS closed and deleted any existing project.lock.json files. Now everything seems to work as intended.

I found this problem to occur on any system with a fresh installation of Windows/VS/tooling so likely a bug with their installers.

Comment: Just fixed my broken nuget package install. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2017 - Update 15.3

You can get around this by doing the following

Edit the `.csproj` File for the .NET Standard Library and add these lines

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
 <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.4' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
 </PropertyGroup>



Other stuff here
 </Project>
```

**PackageTargetFallback** will allow you to use compatible packages that are older.

https://www.cameronmoten.com/2017/08/19/fixing-xamarin-with-net-standard-in-visual-studio-2017-v-15-3/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is missed in your tooling, and the error messaging isn't always the clearest on this. Can you make sure that you have run both the installers here:

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129) (I'm guessing you have this)

[.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546)

I really don't think it's a project file issue, as MailKit is failing for you, and I doubt you broke NuGet. The other bit that might give you some good information if this doesn't work is to run

```
Dotnet restore
```

in the project directory to see how donet handles it without Visual Studio.