# Asp .Net Core - cannot install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget-package

In my Asp .Net Core Web Application (started with empty template) I cannot install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc nuget package.

After pressing Install in Nuget manager I get this error message:

**Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'.**

I tried to solve it on my own, but:

1) My project doesn't have project.json

2) Clearing nuget cache like in this answer didn't help:
   [Netstandard1.x Nuget packages cannot be installed for netstandard1.x projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584699/netstandard1-x-nuget-packages-cannot-be-installed-for-netstandard1-x-projects/39810908#39810908)

Project target framework: .NetCoreApp1.0 (also tried 1.1)

Ide: VS2017 RC

I didn't have problems so far with installing other packages.

Is there a workaround to install mvc package?

Btw. I have to start with empty project template.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I looked harder in nuget package name and discovered that correct package to install should be **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** and not **<s>Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc</s>**.

Silly mistake, I chose most popular package by typing "mvc" in search box.

Comment: Future reference... all .net core packages are now Microsoft.AspNetCore.***