# When I either upgrade a function app to 3.1 or Create a 3.1 function app I get the Following error message

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-function-app

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.3.0 supports:

- monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
- monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
- xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
- xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
- xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
- xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) FunctionApp1    C:\Users\czias\Documents\git-work\iMedSpider\src\dotnet2\DialogMedical\Services\iMedCore\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj   1

I can't find anywhere online where someone has seen this exact thing.

[image]

When I look in the Dependencies\Frameworks\Microsoft.NETCore.App folder (in the project) I see the following: [image]

In the case of upgrading, I am going from .net core 2.2 to 3.1.  And also function app v2 to v3.  But again, happening when I create a branch new Function App project as well.

Also found this in the obj\project.assets.json file:
[image]

Comment: what is the .net version you tried to upgrade from ?may be this package don't support .net core

Comment: Sorry I should add that. I am going from .net core 2.2 to 3.1.  And also function app v2 to v3.   I am not manually adding this System.IO.Compression.ZipFile nuget.

Comment: try to update it using nuget manager or install latest using   Install-Package System.IO.Compression.ZipFile -Version 4.3.0

Comment: I think I tried that. I will try again.  Doing text in file search I see this in it's project.assets.json file. (screen shot added to description)  But why is this happening on "File New" project?

Comment: Trying to get 4.3.0 from nuget gives me this error following by the same error as before: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'FunctionApp1'.

Comment: what is the version of this package on your project Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer try to update it to 3.1.8

Comment: Try [clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584699/netstandard1-x-nuget-packages-cannot-be-installed-for-netstandard1-x-projects/39810908#39810908)?

Comment: There is no Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer in this project.  It's a brand new project.

Comment: I think you will be better reinstalling Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete project.assets.json so that it can be regenerated on next nuget restore.

Then the problem ceased for the newly created app and other function apps that I upgraded after.